# Is it possible to freeze checkbox in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to freeze a checkbox on a form (but not disable it). Is it possible in VBA?

Comment: What do you mean by freeze? Please describe it more accurately.

Comment: I mean, that the user is not able to check or uncheck the checkbox. If I enable or disable the chack box, I have my aim but the color of the checkbox is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stop the user from changing the value by putting some code into the click event of the checkbox..

```
Private Sub MyCheckBox_Click()

Me.MyCheckBox.Value = True

End Sub
```

---

You could also use the `Locked` property.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Me.MyCheckBox.Value = True
Me.MyCheckBox.Locked = True

End Sub
```

---

And you could also use the `BeforeUpdate` event..

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822421(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822421%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: In fact it does not stop user from changing value, but it keeps Checkbox "checked". And what if it supposed to be "unchecked"?

Comment: I don't know.. Maybe `Me.MyCheckBox.Value = False`? I don't understand why the OP would want to "freeze" the value in the checkbox, I was just offering a solution based on the information he had supplied...